# When I select the radio button , it should submit the answer and open next activity in the same time. How can I do that?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to do simple quiz application with multiple choice.When I select radio button, radio button should submit answer and open next activity. In my code There is a 'submit' button. So first select radio button then click submit button and drag the page to open another page but this is not useful. I want to do all of them just select radio button.

```
 public class Question1 extends Fragment {
     RadioButton q1a2;
     Button btn1;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question1, null);
         return v;
     }

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         q1a2 = (RadioButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.q1a2);
         btn1 =(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btn1);

         final SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
         btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                 if(q1a2.isChecked()){
                     editor.putInt("answer_value", 1);
                 }else{
                     editor.putInt("answer_value", 0);
                 }

                 editor.commit();
             }
         });
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using different radio button listeners and submit button to explicitly get the radio button click, use radiogroup with  radio buttons inside it. Then use RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener to get the id of radio button clicked and in same method you can start new activity.

Sample code below:

```
RadioGroup radio = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        radio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                View radioButton = radio.findViewById(checkedId);
                int index = radio.indexOfChild(radioButton);

                switch (index) {
                case 0: // first button
                        break;
                case 1: // second button
                        break;
                    case 3: // third button
                        break;
                    case 4: // fourth button
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view xml you must have RadioGroup in which your RadioButton exists.

```
RadioGroup yourRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
yourRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // Here you can find selected radio button Id.
        // On the basis of Radio Button you can decide it is selected or not

    }
});
```